# How to calculate datetime using fixed working hours

Tags: javascript, datetime

I am attempting to calculate the datetime 31.5 working hours from a given time. A work day starts at 6am and ends at 4:30pm. Weekends are not worked and should be skipped.

My code seems to be on the right track but is not accurate. I also feel like there is a better way to calculate the result without iterating through every minute or second.

My console log is returning
*"There are 29.832222222222224 work hours remaining until Thu Sep 09 2021 12:16:52 GMT-0700 (Pacific Daylight Time)"*

Instead it should be fixed to 31.5 hours, for example: If it is Friday, 08-27-21 at 12:00:00, the function should return Wednesday, 09-01-21 at 13:30:00.

Any suggestions? I'm trying to use only vanilla JS unless there is a library that would help specifically with this.

```js
// Initialize starting values
var timeRemaining = 0;
var startDate = new Date();
var currentDate = new Date();

// Loop until remaining hours is 31.5
while (timeRemaining <= 31.5) {

  // Check if current date is workday
  var weekDay = currentDate.getDay();
  if (weekDay != 0 && weekDay != 6) {

    // Define work day start and end time
    var workdayStart = new Date(currentDate);
    workdayStart.setHours(06, 00, 0);
    var workdayEnd = new Date(currentDate);
    workdayEnd.setHours(16, 30, 0);

    // Calculate time remaining for given work day
    timeRemaining += Math.abs(workdayEnd - currentDate) / 36e5;
  }

  if (timeRemaining >= 21) {
    // Update current date value to next day
    currentDate.setMinutes(currentDate.getMinutes() + 1);
  } else {
    // Update current date value to next day
    currentDate.setDate(currentDate.getDate() + 1);
  }
}

// Output end date
console.log('There are ' + timeRemaining + ' work hours remaining until ' + currentDate);
```

Comment: I think you need something like this `let offset = 0;
if (weekDay === 0) offset = 1;
else if (weekDay === 6) offset = 2;
let workdayStart = new Date(currentDate);
workdayStart.setDate(workdayStart.getDate() + offset);
workdayStart.setHours(6, 00, 0);
let workdayEnd = new Date(currentDate);
workdayEnd.setDate(workdayEnd.getDate() + offset);
workdayEnd.setHours(16, 30, 0);
console.log(weekDay, offset, workdayStart, workdayEnd);`

Comment: Your logic (e.g. `if (timeRemaining >= 19)`) does not make sense to me. Can you clarify your requirement? The duration between  `6am` and `4:30pm` is `10.5 hours` and accordingly, starting from `Friday, 08-27-21 at 12:00:00`, the duration of 28.5 hours will reach at `Wed 9am` (4.5 hours on Fri + 10.5 hours on Mon + 10.5 hours on Tue + 3 hours on Wed) whereas you have mentioned that it should reach at `Wednesday, 09-01-21 at 10:30:00`.

Comment: Apart from this, the way you have done is an extremely inefficient way. Once you will clarify your requirement, I or someone else will help you with a much simpler and efficient solution.

Comment: @ArvindKumarAvinash you are correct, I have edited my code to reflect 10.5 hours per day and 31.5 hours total.

My time ```if (timeRemaining >= 19)``` (now 21)was an attempt at getting timeRemaining to update by minute if near the final 10.5 hour workday. I am very aware of how impractical it is but cannot wrap my head around how to run the calculation efficiently

Comment: @mplungjan can you iterate this nested with the rest of the code? I cannot get it to compile properly with your example. Thanks!

Comment: I tried. I am too tired to finish. I did not post a solution for the same reason, just some code for you to consider

Comment: @mplungjan ok thank you for your time

Answer (score 0):

You have to do some iteration, but you can minimise it given work hours to add and start date (default to current date). Your code only handles a very small part of the problem, it doesn't deal with weekends or part workdays very well. Consider the following algorithm:

1. Shift start to beginning of next work period if it's not in one already
2. Convert time to add into weeks, days and remainder
3. Add weeks, then days, then remainder skipping over weekends
4. Deal with weekends at each step

E.g.

```js
// Add work hours
// Work day is 06:00 to 16:30 (10.5 hrs)
// Work days are Mon - Fri (52.5 hrs/week)
// Hours is decimal hours to 0.25 hrs (15 min)
function addWorkHours(hrs, start = new Date()) {
  let d = new Date(+start);
  
  // If not in work time, go to start of next work day
  // - Before 6:00
  if (d.getHours() < 6 || !(d.getDay() % 6)) {
    d.setHours(6,0,0,0);    
    
  // - After 16:30
  } else if((d.getHours() == 16 && d.getMinutes() > 29) || d.getHours() > 17) {
    d.setHours(6,0,0,0);
    d.setDate(d.getDate() + 1);
  }

  // If now on Sat or Sun, move to Mon
  let day = d.getDay() || 7; // Sun == 7
  if (day > 5) {
    d.setDate(d.getDate() + 8 - day);
  }

  // Start adding
  day = d.getDay() || 7;
  let weeks = Math.floor(hrs / 52.5);
  let days = Math.floor(hrs % 52.5 / 10.5);
  let remHrs = hrs % 10.5;

  //Add weeks
  d.setDate(d.getDate() + weeks * 7);

  // Add days allowing for weekends
  if (days && (day + days > 5)) {
    days += 2;
  }
  d.setDate(d.getDate() + days);

  // Add remaining hours as minutes to allow for decimal hours
  let remMins = remHrs * 60;

  // Get remaining work minutes - d is already set within a work day
  let remWorkMins = 630 - (60 * (d.getHours() - 6)) - d.getMinutes();

  // If remaining mins more than left in work day,
  // Add extra to start of next work day, allow for Sat, Sun, etc.
  if (remMins > remWorkMins) {
    remMins -= remWorkMins;
    d.setHours(6,0,0,0);
    d.setDate(d.getDate() + 1);
    // If hit Sat
    if (d.getDay() == 6) {
      d.setDate(d.getDate() + (d.getDay() == 6? 2 : 1))
    }
  }
  d.setMinutes(d.getMinutes() + remMins);
  // Debug - values adjusted for weekends, overlapping remHrs
  console.log({weeks, days, remHrs})
  return d;
}

// Examples
[{d: new Date()              , h: 4.5 },     // Today, add 4.5 hrs
 {d: new Date(2021, 8, 1,  4), h: 1.25},     // Wed 1 Sep - before start
 {d: new Date(2021, 8, 2, 12), h: 21.5},     // Thu 2 Sep - hit weekend 2d .5h
 {d: new Date(2021, 8, 2, 12), h: 42.5},     // Thu 2 Sep - across weekend 4d .5h
 {d: new Date(2021, 8, 3,  6), h: 22.5},     // Fri 3 Sep - during - into weekend
 {d: new Date(2021, 8, 3, 16), h: 1.25},     // Fri 3 Sep - during - near end
 {d: new Date(2021, 8, 4, 16), h: 1.25},     // Sat 4 Sep - non–work day
 {d: new Date(2021, 8, 4,  4), h: 1.25},     // Sat 4 Sep - non–work day
 {d: new Date(2021, 8, 4, 12), h: 1.25},     // Sat 4 Sep - non–work day
 {d: new Date(2021, 8, 6, 12), h: 1.25},     // Mon 6 Sep - during
 {d: new Date(2021, 8, 6, 16), h: 1.25},     // Mon 6 Sep - during - near end
 {d: new Date(2021, 8, 7, 16, 45), h: 1.25}, // Tue 7 Sep - after end
 {d: new Date(2021, 8, 7, 16, 45), h: 201.5},// Tue 7 Sep - after end, add work 19 days and 1.5 work hours
].forEach(({d, h}) =>
  console.log('Adding: ' + h + ' work hours' +
    '\n' + d.toString() + 
    '\n' + addWorkHours(h, d).toString()
  )
);
```

Note that output *weeks*, *days*, *remHrs* have been adjusted for weekends and overlap of the working day.

The above expects the work hours to be in even multiples of 0.25 hours, otherwise you'll get issues with ECMAScript's decimal arithmetic. If you want to work in smaller units (minutes, seconds) you'll need to work in milliseconds and round at appropriate points.

You can make bespoke functions for adding days and hours so you don't have to deal with it more than once, but those functions end up being longer than they need because the logic is slightly different depending on where it's called from. By doing it in the sequence above, some issues are fixed before calling the function (e.g. first step is to make sure the start is in a work period, etc.).